# Formik: getting values of specific components

Tags: reactjs, formik

**I'm using Formik with Yup in my Reactjs App to get signup information.**

But I'm having issues with specific components like MultiSelect or CountryDropdown because the Formik Values don't handle their onChange and so they don't get whatever value is in there.
How to do that?

**Code example:**

```
<Field
      fullWidth
      name="specialities"
      component={Multiselect}
      label="Specialities"
      isObject={false}
      options={specialities}
      placeholder="Select your specialities"
/>
```

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: According to the docs "Custom React components will be passed onChange, onBlur, name, and value plus any other props passed to directly to <Field>" which means you could wrap Multiselect in your own component that receives `onChange` and call it when the Multiselect value becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

**You can access all field values from the callback arguments:**

```
<Formik>
        {(props) => {
          const { values } = props; // <--- All your values are here!
          return (
            <Field
              fullWidth
              name="specialities"
              component={Multiselect}
              label="Specialities"
              isObject={false}
              options={specialities}
              placeholder="Select your specialities"
            />
          );
        }}
</Formik>
```